# How to change HTML attributes in a raw string with Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I want to take a bunch of anchor tags and make sure that they all open in a new tab.

I know I should do something like this `$('a').attr('target', '_blank');` but the catch is that the HTML I am trying to modify is in a string variable.

See example:

I have a bunch of raw HTML in a string like this:

```
var rawHTML = 'Hello there, <a href="http://www.google.com">this</a> is a link.'
```

How can I convert that to be something like this:

```
processedHTML = 'Hello there, <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">this</a> is a link.'
```

Comment: add string starting at a specific index

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using jQuery you can append the string to an element outside of the DOM

You can then use jQuery methods on this new element to modify the html and then return the modified string:

```
var rawHTML = 'Hello there, <a href="http://www.google.com">this</a> is a link.';
// create element and set string as it's content
var $div = $('<div>').html(rawHTML);
// modify attributes
$div.find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
// return modified content to string
var processedHTML = $div.html();
```

Answer (score 3):

In pure JavaScript, we can do this by making use of the [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`Element.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), and [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) methods, as well as the [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) getter & setter property.

Note that [`Element.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an *live* [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is why we can instantiate the `links` object *before* we insert the `html` string. To iterate on the collection, we invoke an array method with the collection as the `this` context.

This reduces some of the overhead of jQuery.

```js
function blankify (html) {
  var root = document.createElement('span'),
      links = root.getElementsByTagName('a');
  
  root.innerHTML = html;
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function (e) {
    e.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  });
  
  return root.innerHTML;
}

console.log(blankify('Hello there, <a href="http://www.google.com">this</a> is a link.'));
```

And just because, here's a fairly flexible jQuery method. Works on the DOM, and is chainable.

```js
jQuery.prototype.blankify = function () {
  return this.find('a').attr('target', '_blank'), this;
};

console.log($('<span/>', {
  html: 'Hello there, <a href="http://www.google.com">this</a> is a link.'
}).blankify().html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer doesn't have more upvotes, i think this should have been the accepted one because a plain JS solution is way more portable than a vendor lock-in.