# How to make just links lowercase in a line of HTML?

Tags: regex, hyperlink, lowercase

I have several large HTML menu files that contain several thousand links that need to be made lowercase - but nothing else.

An entire line looks like this.

```
<li><strong><a href="pages\SDL_RenderDrawLine.htm">SDL_RenderDrawLine</a></strong> - draw a line.</li>
```

The link is the only part that needs to be lowercase... actually just the part between quote marks (if that makes it easier); but the rest of the line should remain untouched.

```
<a href="pages\SDL_RenderDrawLine.htm">

"pages\SDL_RenderDrawLine.htm"
```

What would be an efficient way to do this?

*Thanks for the help (and saving me a ton of editing!)*

Comment: Don't do this with a regexp. Use a DOM parser, then you can easily replace the `href` attribute.

Comment: IIRC correctly regex itself (all flavors) doesn't have a feature to convert the match into lowercase. You will eventually have to use a programming language, so do this the correct way, as suggested above.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I am well aware of the lower: upper: case commands. They are not applicable in this case because (as I mentioned)  I only want strings between quotes in lower case, not the whole line. So I need to just parse the quotes some way.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. We don't mark questions [solved] here. You'll need to accept your answer if it's the best one.

Comment: Per Barmar's comment, see [How to change HTML attributes in a raw string with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766825/how-to-change-html-attributes-in-a-raw-string-with-jquery-or-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround that is not elegant but works.

First, I changed field (2) to lowercase using quotes as the field separator.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\"" }  {print ($1)"\""tolower($2)"\""$3}' test.txt > temp
```

This made the links (2nd col) lowercase.

> [ Prior problem fixed - with help from commenter: ...but unfortunately removed the
> quotes ' " ' being used as a field separator.
>
> Then I manually used a text editor to search and replace the quotes '
> " ' back into the files.
>
> I am sure someone more experienced with awk knows how to keep the
> field separators in the output, but this got the job done! ]